# Which db type has to used when passing an object to procedure in a oracle package using ODP.NET (C #)?

Tags: c#, c, oracle, odp.net

Hi I am passing an object to procedure in a oracle package using ODP.NET(C#). I am using ODP.NET because of associative arrays. I am unable to find oracledbtype.object in the ODP.NET to make parameter oracledbtype to object. which dbtype I have to use for parameter in .NET side using ODP.NET.

```
         public Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand oc = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand();



        oc.Parameters.Add("Param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = txt_RequestId.Text;

        //assign the array to the parm
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter additionalBusiness_AssocParm = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter();

        // When I tried to assign parameter OracleDbType to Varchar2 it is generating an error [PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERT_REQUEST'].
        // When I tried to change that value to Object. It is giving compliation error that object dbtype doesn't exist in Oracle.Data.Client.OracleDbType
        additionalBusiness_AssocParm.OracleDbType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        additionalBusiness_AssocParm.CollectionType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
        additionalBusiness_AssocParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        additionalBusiness_AssocParm.Value = unitId; // unitId is an array of User defined type
        oc.Parameters.Add(additionalBusiness_AssocParm);

        try
        {
            DoQueryWithODP("TEST_PKG.INSERT_UNIT", true);
        }
```

Comment: can you post some code to make this more apparent?  are you receiving an error? if so, what is it?  there is an [Object type](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E15167_01/featOraCommand.htm#i1007297) but I would like to see what is happening on your side before venturing a guess.

Comment: can you post the spec for test_pkg.insert_unit as well as the definition of hte associative array?

Answer (score 1):

okay, I'll try to tackle this one without your pl/sql specification but we'll see how this works.

I will use the sample provided in the ODP installation @ %ORA_HOME%\odp.net\samples\2.x\AssocArray\AssocArray.sln
as a sample talking point.
but this site is also helpful
[Using PL/SQL Associative Arrays](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17odp-093600.html)  (this is actually off of a link in the article provided by mservidio, wheras that article was about *ArrayBind* not *Associative Arrays*)

---

```
CREATE TABLE TestAssociativeArray(COL1 varchar2(20), COL2 varchar2(20)) ;
/
create or replace PACKAGE MyTestAssociativeArray AS 
   TYPE AssocArrayVarchar2_t is table of VARCHAR(20) index by BINARY_INTEGER;
    PROCEDURE TestVarchar2(Param1 IN TestAssociativeArray.COL1%type ,
                           Param2 IN AssocArrayVarchar2_t);
END MyTestAssociativeArray ;
/
create or replace package body MyTestAssociativeArray as
    PROCEDURE TestVarchar2(Param1 IN TestAssociativeArray.COL1%type ,
                           Param2 IN AssocArrayVarchar2_t) 
    AS
    i INTEGER ; 
    BEGIN
        FOR i in Param2.first..Param2.last LOOP
            insert into TestAssociativeArray(col1, col2) 
                        values (Param1 , Param2(i)) ;
        END LOOP ;
    END TestVarchar2 ;
END MyTestAssociativeArray  ;
/
```

---

now for the .net code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // Connect
  string connectStr = getConnection();

  // Setup the Tables for sample

  OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectStr);
  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("MyTestAssociativeArray.TestVarchar2", connection);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;

  OracleParameter param1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
  OracleParameter param2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("param2", OracleDbType.Varchar2);

  // Setup the direction
  param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
  param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

  // Specify that we are binding PL/SQL Associative Array
  param2.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;

  param1.Value = "ConstantValue" ;
  param2.Value = new string[3]{"Val1",
                               "Val2",
                               "Val3"};


  try 
  {
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }

}
```

---

and the results (with cleanup)

```
select * from TestAssociativeArray
/
COL1                 COL2                 
-------------------- -------------------- 
ConstantValue        Val1                 
ConstantValue        Val2                 
ConstantValue        Val3  
/** --clean up
drop package MyTestAssociativeArray;
drop table TestAssociativeArray ;
**/
```

However, since you haven't posted your spec, it may be something as simple as:
needing:

```
cmd.BindByName = true;
```

[since ODP by default binds by position AND not by name](http://oradim.blogspot.com/2007/08/odpnet-tip-bind-variables-and.html) (this trips up a lot of people)

Answer (score 0):

This should have all the information you need. I've used this article before to perform what you're trying.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html

Comment: Not on a computer with odac installed so I can't give a sample.

Comment: the OP asked about **Associative** Array binding, not ArrayBind methodology (similar but not the same!)